# Break up row in 2 at specific place if screen size is less than 768px in html only

Tags: html

I have set up a table and I need it to break it up at a specific place.

The row should break in 2 rows if the screen size is less than 768px. And the new line should start with Food & Drink cell.

Here is the table.

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table align="center" bgcolor="#006432" border="5" bordercolor="white" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <td style="text-align: center;" width="12.5%">
          <font color="white">Livestock<br />&amp; dairy</font>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center;" width="12.5%">
          <font color="white">Business management</font>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center;" width="12.5%">
          <font color="white">Climate<br />&amp; enviroment</font>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center;" width="12.5%">
          <font color="white">Soils<br />&amp; crop</font>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center;" width="12.5%">
          <font color="white">Food<br />&amp; drink</font>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center;" width="12.5%">
          <font color="white">National programms</font>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center;" width="12.5%">
          <font color="white">Grants &amp; schemes </font>
        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center;" width="12.5%">
          <font color="white">New entrants</font>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Are there any solution in just HTML without CSS?

Thanks, 
m.

Comment: Either you'll need to use HTML + Javascript, or HTML + CSS. HTML alone is totally static and has no features to support this.

Comment: Tables are not good for responsive re-arrange. Use `<div>`'s instead.

Comment: Try look into "media queries" `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { //css goes here }`

Answer (score 0):

As @PeterB said it's not possible to add rows to a table without using Javascript.

If it is possible you can add a Listener for the `resize` event on the window global object with Javascript. (doc: [resize - Event reference | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize))

Using CSS you have some solutions with media queries.

In HTML you could use the `<wbr>` tag in some elements (`<div>`, `<p>`, etc.) (doc: [wbr  | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr)).

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;font-size:6em;color:white;background:#006432;" align="center">
  <p>Livestock <wbr>&amp; dairy</p>
  <p>Business management</p>
  <p>Climate <wbr>&amp; enviroment</p>
  <p>Soils <wbr>&amp; crop</p>
  <p>Food <wbr>&amp; drink</p>
  <p>National programms</p>
  <p>Grants <wbr>&amp; schemes</p>
  <p>New entrants</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, I got an update from cms developers who recommended to use this instead. And gave option how I could use css as well not only HTMl.

Thanks @PeterB and @Chocolord for your advice and tips! highly appreciated.

```html
<ul id="flex-list">
 <li>Livestock dairy</li>
  <li>Business management</li>
  <li>Climate enviroment</li>
  <li>Soils crop</li>
  <li>Food drink</li>
  <li>National programms</li>
  <li>Grants schemes</li>
  <li>New entrants</li>
</ul>

<style>
 #flex-list {
 background-color: rgb(0,100,50);
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 align-items: stretch;
 justify-content: center;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;}

#flex-list li {
 text-align: center;
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 min-width: 98px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
 margin-top: -1px;
 margin-right: -1px;}

#flex-list a {color: #fff;}

 @media screen and (max-width: 1034px) {#flex-list li {min-width: 178px; }}

 @media screen and (max-width: 880px) {#flex-list li {min-width: 248px;}}

 @media screen and (max-width:488px) {#flex-list {display: block;}}

 </style>
```